# Why the set S(t) is the subspace of the null space of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

The picture below is on the page 5 of the paper [*On linear differential-algebraic equations and linearizations*](https://sci-hub.tw/10.1016/0168-9274(95)00058-3).

[image: pic from the paper]

What I have learnt from the pic is as follows:

1. $N(t):=ker A(t)\subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is that $N(t)$ is the solution space of $A(t)x=0$.
2. $B(t)z \in \mathbb{im} \: A(t)$ is that $\forall z,\exists y, B(t)z=A(t)y$

So why we can get $S(t)$ is the subspace of the solution space of $A(t)x'(t)+B(t)x(t)=0, \: t\in J$

And what book do I need read next?

Thanks

Comment: What they mean by "$S(t)$ is the subspace where the homogeneous solutions proceed" is that for the homogeneous equation, $x(t)$ has to lie in $S(t)$. This is because otherwise it would not be possible to satisfy the homogeneous equation for any value of $x'(t)$.

Comment: @Rahul   Sorry, i don't know,That "$S(t)$ is the subspace of the homogeneous equation solutions" is that $\forall z \in S(t)$ is the solution of   $A(t)x'(t)+B(t)x(t)=0$?? And $A(t)z'+B(t)z=0, B(t)z=A(t)y$